# Facebook API posts don't get any reach

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have a PHP program that is set up to make a Facebook post to a page I manage through the curl API call. Everything works correctly and the post is made and can be seen when you go on to the page, however it never gets any organic reach. Normal posts that are made by the page through the actual Facebook engine get a descent organic reach, but the posts made programmatically never do. Has anybody else had this issue/ have a solution for this?

Comment: are you sure the post is visible to other users? is your app in dev mode?

Comment: @luschn I am certain it is in production. The curl call looks like this: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/feed/message=THE_MESSAGE&link=URL&place=LOCATION&access_token=TOKEN

I have also noticed that the place variable will not post the location that is set.